# JSF Compare to lists

Tags: jsf, primefaces, compare

how can I compare two lists in JSF:

I have a p:dataTable.
I have two entities:
1. User
2. Friendship (has a sender and a receiver as attribute)

Relationship:
User 1...n Friendship

My datatable is a list of Users.
My requirement is now to validate if the login user already send or receive a friendship.
Something like this

```
<p:dataTable var="user" ...
...
   <p:column>
       <h:outputText value="#{loginUserBean.friendship.contains(currentRowUser.friendship)}>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: In `loginUserBean` create method hasFriendship with parameter User and move checking in Java. In xhtml call it: `<h:outputText value="#{loginUserBean.hasFriendship(user)} />`

Comment: Can I use this in a p:datatable? I mean for every row? If i have 400 rows, the hasFriendship method will call 400 times? Is this right? Are there no specific Expression Language codes for this?

Comment: Yes, it will call per each row. If you add pagination with 10 or 20 rows per page, then number of call is equal of numbers of rows per page (10 or 20). When value is EL expression, then there is still backing bean call. In your case it is `loginUserBean.someMethod`.

Comment: Proper way for you is preparing list with all data for datatable in initView method and display data (from this list) in datatable without any additional calculation.